# How to solve $e^x=kx + 1$ when $k > 1$?

Tags: roots

It's obvious that $x=0$ is one of the roots. According to the graphs of $e^x$ and $kx + 1$, there's another root $x_1 > 0$ when $k > 1$. Is there a way to represent it numerically.

Comment: I believe there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions. They can be computed numerically, of course. (When $k<1$ there should be second solutions, too, but they should be with $x_1<0$.)

Comment: have you tried newton with a start value greater then 1

Comment: You are trying to compute the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, essentially.

Comment: the solution contains the product logarithmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t = -x - 1/k$, we have $$t e^t = (-x - 1/k) e^{-x} e^{-1/k} = - e^{-1/k}/k $$ 
The solutions of this are $t = W(-e^{-1/k}/k)$, i.e. $$x = - W(-e^{-1/k}/k) - 1/k$$ where $W$ is one of the branches of the Lambert W function.
If $k > 1$, $-e^{-1/k}/k \in (-1/e,0)$, and there are two real branches: the $0$ branch (which gives you $x=0$), and the $-1$ branch, which gives you the solution you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though it's my first time to look into the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x=kx+1$$
$$x=\log(1+kx)$$
so
$$x=\log(1+k\log(1+k\log(1+k\log(1+....))))$$

Comment: Assuming that converges, of course. And it might not converge to anything other than $0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have checked it for many values of $x,k$ when they greater than 1, all the cases were converge

Comment: Sorry, but what is your starting value for $x_0$? "I have checked it for many values" is not what we call proof in mathematics, although it is likely true.